# Is there a way to compress multiple signatures of the same data?

Tags: signature, compression

So, I'm working with a system that allows individual users to each have their own private-public key pair.

I would like to allow multiple users to use their private key to sign the same piece of information to confirm they agree with something.  By signature, I mean the public key can be used to check the signature is valid.

However, space is at a premium.  So is there a way to compress those multiple signatures of the same data?

Using Curve25519, but other algorithms might be acceptable.

Comment: Aggregate Signatures are more general than that, but might offer you what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use multi-signatures.

One example is the BN06 scheme described in the paper:
[Bellare, Neven - Multi-signatures in the plain public-Key model and a general forking lemma](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~mihir/papers/multisignatures-ccs.pdf)

Comment: You may also take a look at [this paper](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~aboldyre/papers/b.html).

Comment: Actually, I think that multiple signatures work the wrong way.

I would like for anyone on the network to prove that it was signed by someone with a given public key.  This is more anonymous and allows them to use their private key to prove they are a signer but not allow others to look at a multisignature and say that it was signed by public key x,y, and z, right?

Comment: @user127317 : $\;\;\;$ Do you need showings of [ownership](http://www.bolet.org/~pornin/2005-acns-pornin+stern.pdf)? $\:$ That does not necessarily disallow the latter. $\:$ You might be interested in some sort of [undeniable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undeniable_signature) multi-signature. $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Yes, I need to from a signature, be able to say that account A,B,C,... verify that this information is correct.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think a reduction based on repeated messages with possible with normal ECC signatures (ECDSA, ElGamal, EdDSA, etc.).

A few alternative approaches:

- **public key recovery**

  This doesn't reduce the size of the signature itself, but you don't need to transmit the public key alongside the signature. If applicable, this gains you 2 times the security level in size.
- **Hashed Schnorr signatures.**

  This reduces the signature size to 3 times the security level (instead of 4 times the security level)

  Not sure how this interacts with multi target attacks.
- **BLS signatures**

  Signature size is only 2 times the security level.

Comment: Not having to transmit the public key alongside the signature would be a very nice speed up as our public keys are 32B or 64B each on their own.